# Avro schema evolution

Tags: avro

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to use the same reader and parse records that were written with two schemas that are compatible, e.g. `Schema V2` only has an additional optional field compared to `Schema V1` and I want the reader to understand both? I think the answer here is no, but if yes, how do I do that?
2. I have tried writing a record with `Schema V1` and reading it with `Schema V2`, but I get the following error:

   org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found foo, expecting foo

I used avro-1.7.3 and:

```
   writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericData.Record>(SchemaV1);
   reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericData.Record>(SchemaV2, SchemaV1);
```

Here are examples of the two schemas (I have tried adding a namespace as well, but no luck).

Schema V1:

```
{
"name": "foo",
"type": "record",
"fields": [{
    "name": "products",
    "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "name": "product",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "a1",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "a2",
                "type": {"type": "fixed", "name": "a3", "size": 1}
            }, {
                "name": "a4",
                "type": "int"
            }, {
                "name": "a5",
                "type": "int"
            }]
        }
    }
}]
}
```

Schema V2:

```
{
"name": "foo",
"type": "record",
"fields": [{
    "name": "products",
    "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "name": "product",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "a1",
                "type": "string"
            }, {
                "name": "a2",
                "type": {"type": "fixed", "name": "a3", "size": 1}
            }, {
                "name": "a4",
                "type": "int"
            }, {
                "name": "a5",
                "type": "int"
            }]
        }
    }
},
{
            "name": "purchases",
            "type": ["null",{
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                            "name": "purchase",
                            "type": "record",
                            "fields": [{
                                    "name": "a1",
                                    "type": "int"
                            }, {
                                    "name": "a2",
                                    "type": "int"
                            }]
                    }
            }]
}]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same issue. That might be a bug of avro, but you probably can work around by adding "default": null to the field of "purchase".

Check my blog for details: http://ben-tech.blogspot.com/2013/05/avro-schema-evolution.html

Comment: Default values are a must when using schema evolution. If you do not provide a default value for a field that is present in the reader schema, but not in the writer schema, Avro can't figure out how to create this new field in the parsed structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do opposite of it . Mean you can parse data schem 1 and write data from schema 2 . Beacause at write time it write data into file and if we don't provide any field at reading time than it will be ok. But if we write less field than read than it will not recognize extra field at reading time so , it will give error .

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to have a schema mapping to maintain the schema like Confluent Avro schema registry.

**Key Take Aways:**

```
1.  Unlike Thrift, avro serialized objects do not hold any schema.
2.  As there is no schema stored in the serialized byte array, one has to provide the schema with which it was written.
3.  Confluent Schema Registry provides a service to maintain schema versions.
4.  Confluent provides Cached Schema Client, which checks in cache first before sending the request over the network.
5.  Json Schema present in “avsc” file is different from the schema present in Avro Object.
6.  All Avro objects extends from Generic Record
7.  During Serialization : based on schema of the Avro Object a schema Id is requested from the Confluent Schema Registry.
8.  The schemaId which is a INTEGER is converted to Bytes and prepend to serialized AvroObject.
9.  During Deserialization : First 4 bytes are removed from the ByteArray.  4 bytes are converted back to INTEGER(SchemaId)
10. Schema is requested from the Confluent Schema Registry and using this schema the byteArray is deserialized.
```

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/avro/avro-serialization-de-serialization-using-confluent-schema-registry/